# Unable to parse XML dynamically

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xml-parsing

In the JavaScript code below it works for first loop but for the second loop it always shows y.length equals 0 and never enters the loop. The y.length is not zero, my xml file has lot of my thing. I tried debugging but could not go any further. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function myXML(myText, myTarget) {
    try {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(myText);
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(myText, "text/xml");
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
            return;
        }
    }
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("myThing");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstItem")[0].hasChildNodes) {
            document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = document.getElementById(myTarget).innerHTML + x[i].getElementsByTagName("secondThing")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " - " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstItem")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            var response = "";
            var sid = x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../sitman/requests/get_affected_nodes.cgi?sid=" + sid,
                async: false,
                success: function(text) {
                    response = text;
                }
            });
            try {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = "false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    parser = new DOMParser();
                    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                    return;
                }
            }
            var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("myThing");
            for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
                document.getElementById(myTarget).innerHTML = document.getElementById(myTarget).innerHTML + y[j].getElementsByTagName("myname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XML for y is below.

```
<xml>
<entries>
<myThing>
<myName>xxx</myName>
<test1>test8</test1>
<test2>test6</test2>
</myThing>
<myThing>
<myName>xxx</myName>
<test1>test2</test1>
<test2>test3</test2>
</myThing>
</entries>
</xml>
```

Comment: `y` equals `0`??? Did you mean `y.length == 0`?

Comment: Just use `dataType: "xml"` and don't fire up your own `DOMParser`? (btw, ActiveX should be the fallback for the standard DOMParser not the other way round)

Comment: Yes I mean y.length. I will correct that and still not working.

Comment: And what does `console.log(xmlDoc)` show you, a parse error maybe?

Comment: Yes, its showing parser error. Document is empty.

Comment: Now you know why `y.length` is zero on an empty document :-) Does it tell you about the parse error reason, or do you need further help with it?

Comment: I am confused why I am getting parsing error, the first x is parsing the exact same way and it works fine but y has a valid xml and everything and the syntax is same. Why am I getting parse error any help will be grateful.

Comment: Then you will need to post the full xml (or better, the `response` variable value) and the error message you're getting.

Comment: The response is document and the content is xml as above, I have updated xml. The error message is document is empty for xmlDoc.

Comment: You say the `response` is a document already, not a string?

Comment: Yes its a document. Does it need to be string. If so how do I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed several problems in your code. First, you're accessing an undefine variable *target* in this line:

```
document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = document.getElementById(myTarget).innerHTML + x[i].getElementsByTagName("secondThing")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " - " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstItem")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
```

Assumedly that *target* should have been *myTarget*.

Then you're parsing the ajax response with this:

```
try {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
} catch (e) {
    try {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
        return;
    }
}
```

But the response is already an XML object. You can replace that whole section with:

```
xmlDoc = response;
```

Finally, in the last for loop over y, you've got this call:

```
y[j].getElementsByTagName("myname")
```

But in the XML, the name of the element is actually `myName`.

I've created a test server with all of these things fixed, at it appeared to work ok for me, so I think that's all you need to fix.

Comment: Thank you james target and myname were typo, I had those things correct but after I replaced try catch with xmlDoc = response; It worked it just not looking for all x which I will try to figure out. Thank you anyway.